# How to replace porch joists?

Tags: joists, porch

[image]

My covered porch has seen some better days. The 2x10 joists are rotted on top causing the wood on top to sag. The 2x10 is notched and inserted into the brick on both sides. I have a feeling that this was done while the house was being built. This makes it impossible to replace them without changing something and all the joists need to be replaced.

My questions is: what is the preferred method for doing this type of repair?

Would I attach a ledger board to the house and notch in the joists on the other side or put up two ledger boards. Perhaps there is some trick or system that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends how far those holes go. if you can over-feed one end of the joist, you can then align the other end with with the other hole and 
back it in.

ledgers, as you suggest are a legitimate solution too, also brackets, but on brick ledgers are easier.

ledgers both sides is probably the easiest to get right. you're then not relying on any unseen features of the building construction, and avoiding any potential unpleasant surprises.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you could go about repair/replacement. Sister your new joists to the old, tear out the old deck entirely and do a floating deck, or ledgers with hangers. Your choice, and depends on the size of the porch/deck, cost of repair/rebuild and any possible code requirements.

Comment: Sistering a treated 2x6 to the side/top of each 2x10 is what I would try first. It would be the least expensive method that solves the problem of the rotted tops of the 2x10s. This will support your existing decking and eliminate the sagging. It's a cheap enough solution that it's worth trying before replacing everything. It might get you 10 more years of use.